# How to place outlook add-in in email itself for read email form

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Basically I want to show the add-in for all clients (Outlook and Outlook web) in the add-in area in the email, as shown below in red

[wanted](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/24508594/111737489-ae083480-88ba-11eb-80cc-2294a6004631.png)

currently **my add-in shows up in ribbon**, I want to place **my add-in in email read form** itself for all outlook client

expected UI:
**my add-in in email read form**

[outlook-btn-in-email](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/24508594/111633777-d3506080-8830-11eb-958d-8abdb2b1dcd9.png)

current UI:
**my add-in shows up in ribbon**

[outlook-btn-in-ribbon](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/24508594/111633789-d6e3e780-8830-11eb-8028-2230d4e283ed.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the behaviour you marked as expected has now been deprecated. The ribbon is the default for all Outlook [AppCommands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/add-in-commands-for-outlook) right now.